# How to not pushing the navigation bar during a segue ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, segue

I'm creating an iOS app which has two screens. There is a search bar common to the two screens : this is the view of my navigation bar.

I would like that when the segue is performed between the two screens, the navigation bar (i. e. the search bar) is not pushed. It is for an aesthetic reason : the search bar doesn't change between the two screens, so pushing it is useless.

Do you know how can I do this please ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to keep the navigation/search bar in place when segueing from a view controller to the next one (if I understand your question correctly). A feasible approach would be to design separate views in a view controller and swap only the views, thus keeping the navigation/search bar in place.

Comment: Oh, it seems interesting. What is the name of this possibility please ?

Comment: Not everything has a name. Use your creativity with UIViews and their properties.

Comment: I guess this post is also asking for something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778215/ios-add-a-vc-above-existing-vc